# Dropbox falling on browser everytime i upload a file

Tags: android, dropbox-api

i have multiple places where my app should upload files to Dropbox. when i try to upload a file the app is falling back to browser. if i use the DropboxApi object globally it says DropboxUnlinkedException.
I am posting  my code

Dropbox.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
    AJ_Constant.mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    // Basic Android widgets
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (mLoggedIn) {
        logOut();
    } else {
        // Start the remote authentication
        AJ_Constant.mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DropBox.this);
       }
    }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Mandatory call to complete the auth
            session.finishAuthentication();

            // Store it locally in our app for later use
            TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:"
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
        }
}
}
```

The code for uploading file is : 
(this code is in another file _someX.java)

```
com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry response = AJ_Constant.mApi.putFile(
                    AJ_Constant.ReportfileName, inputStream, file.length(),
                    null, null);
```

Should i re-build the session or get authentication process done everytime??
Please suggest me any solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: I see the code where you're storing the access token pair after authorization, but I don't see where you're using that token pair the next time the app is run. Could you share that part of your code?

Comment: @smarx : i am not using it anywhere. how should i use that token pair for creating a session ? can you please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Android SDK docs](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/index.html) (note the last line of code):

> A typical authentication flow when no user access token pair is saved
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
> AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(myAppKeys, myAccessType);
>
> // When user wants to link to Dropbox, within an activity:
> session.startOAuth2Authentication(this);
>
> // When user returns to your activity, after authentication:
> if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
>   try {
>     session.finishAuthentication();
>
>     AccessTokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
>     // Store tokens.key, tokens.secret somewhere
>   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>     // Error handling
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> When a user returns to your app and you have tokens stored, just
>   create a new session with them:
>
> ```
> AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(
>   myAppKeys, myAccessType, new AccessTokenPair(storedAccessKey, storedAccessSecret));
> ```